# Instantiating a Class in C++: Strange Syntax Bug

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I've never run into this before in C++ but it's odd that it still compiles but doesn't do what I expected. Can someone tell me what it does do?  Please see the code, more info follows.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    public:
        Test();
};

Test::Test(){ cout << "ctor" << endl; }

int main(void){

    Test t();  // this compiles but doesn't call the constructor

    return(0);
}
```

It will compile, but if I try to use "t" it won't. I was only dependent on constructor functionality, and my code didn't work as expected.  The solution is to lose the parenthesis "Test t();" to "Test t;". My question is what is going on in the "Test t();" example, and what does the compiler think is happening that it lets it compile.

Comment: Look up most vexing parse.

Comment: Welcome to your Rite of Passage.

Comment: The question is...did the compiler know what you were expecting? :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This was my first question on SO and I'm amazed it got answered so quickly.  I laughed out loud when I saw the answer. It's obvious once you know you can declare functions in other functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Basically, according to the C++ parsing rules, what you have there isn't an object of type `Test` named `t`, but rather a function declaration for a function `t` which takes zero arguments and returns a `Test`.

Incidentally, clang++ actually recognizes this situation and emits a warning, telling you that this probably isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Can we declare/define functions in other functions? I assumed not?

Comment: @KarthikT: I don't think you can define nested functions in C++, but you can certainly declare them. For example, this works just fine: `int main() { void foo(); foo(); } void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }`

Comment: @Karthik: Functions can be *declared* inside other functions. This is the case since C.

Comment: @AndreyT I see.. Does this add value? Looks like easiest way to fix this problem is to remove that feature.

Comment: @KarthikT: the fix, since c++11, is to use the {} syntax. `Test t{};` is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that is aptly named as the *most vexing parse*. Your line `Test t();` can be interpreted in one of two ways.

1. It can declare a variable `t` which is of type `Test`
2. It can declare a function `t()`, which returns a `Test` value and takes no arguments

The C++ standard unfortunately requires the compiler to consider the second alternative, which is quite a vexing parse.

The easiest way to *fix* that parse is to get rid of the parenthesis and simply declare your variable as such :

```
Test t; // Will call the default constructor
```